# Converse to extreme value theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, compactness, semicontinuous-functions, extreme-value-theorem

It's well known that continuous functions achieve minima on compact sets. An even stronger result is that lower semicontinuous functions achieve minima on compact sets.

**Question.** If an extended-real function $f$ attains a minimum on every compact subset of a topological space  $X$, does it follow that $f$ is lower semicontinuous?

If it helps, I'm happy to assume that $X$ is a convex and compact subset of a locally convex TVS and that $f$ is convex.

Comment: Another interesting question is to characterise topological spaces on which every continuous real valued function achieves minima.  These are called *real compact* spaces and the better known example of a non-compact one is the first uncountable ordinal with the order topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the following function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x\neq 0$},\\
1, & \text{if $x = 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$
It attains a minimum on every (compact) set, but it is not l.s.c.